# TypeError[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null

Tags: windows, postgresql, express, environment-variables

I'm trying to get my express app to connect to my local DB by I am getting an error when running my express app:

> TypeError[ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "key" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, DataView, or KeyObject. Received null

My DB configuration settings are used like so:

```
const herokuSSLSetting = { rejectUnauthorized: false };
// If local env variable is declared, turn ssl settings off
const sslSetting = process.env.LOCAL ? false : herokuSSLSetting;
const dbConfig = {
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: sslSetting,
};

const app = express();

app.use(express.json()); //add body parser to each following route handler
app.use(cors()); //add CORS support to each following route handler

const client = new Client(dbConfig);
```

Now when I use my heroku DATABASE_URL, that works fine. I believe the issue is coming from when I declare LOCAL=true in my env file. If I remove that line when connecting to my local db, the error then becomes:

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: The server does not support SSL connections

This configuration has worked on my virtual workspace (for local and heroku db) so I think it may be a windows issue...

Other details:

- Running on windows
- Using postgres for my db
- Can connect to my local db via beekeeper by providing the user, password and default db